# Deduce template parameter of class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-deduction, template-templates

Can someone please help me to understand why the following code does not compile:

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T >
class A
{};

template< typename T >
class B
{};

template< template <typename T> class GENERAL_t,  // Note: GENERAL_t is either A<T> or B<T>
          typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T,int>::value >
        >
void foo( GENERAL_t a )
{}
```

error message:

```
t.cpp:67:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
              typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T,int>::value >
                                                        ^
t.cpp:67:65: error: no type named 'value' in the global namespace
              typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T,int>::value >
                                                              ~~^
t.cpp:69:15: error: use of class template 'GENERAL_t' requires template arguments
    void foo( GENERAL_t a )
              ^
t.cpp:66:43: note: template is declared here
    template< template <typename T> class GENERAL_t,  // Note: GENERAL_t is either A<T> or B<T>
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ^
3 errors generated.
```

Here, `foo` should take instances of `class A` or `class B` but only when the template argument `T` of `A` or `B` is an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you haven't declared `T`. It needs to be a template parameter.
- drop the `T` in the `template <class T> class GENERAL_t`
- `GENERAL_t` is a template template and as such requires a template parameter.
- please don't use ALL_CAPS for anything except macros

This is the working code:

```
template<class T, template <class> class General_t, 
          class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T,int>::value >
        >
void foo(General_t<T> a)
{}
```

Answer (score 4):

[bolov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565616/2069064) is correct in all respects.

But in this case, you don't need the SFINAE on `is_same`. You can just template on the template-template:

```
template <template <class> class General>
void foo(General<int> ) { }
```